# Spacing in moderncv fancy theme with multiple line captions

Tags: spacing, moderncv

When I add a long caption for a section or subsection in the moderncv fancy theme, then the second line of the section/subsection will be printed below the last line of the caption, what seems wrong to me. 
Sure, i can play around with vspace to get the line back to were it belongs, but this is really uncool and dirty. Is there another way to do this? Heres a minimal example of what is happening:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{fancy}             
\firstname{Lieselotte}
\familyname{Meier}

\begin{document}

\section{This is the caption of a section or subsection taking two or more lines}
\cvlistdoubleitem{A double item}{But may also be a cvline or a cvitem}
\cvline{in all the cases}{there will be to much space above this}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Section and the listdoubleite arre on the same line. `\cvline` which is obsolete by the way, is on a new line. There is nothing much you can do here, but smuggle the information into the listitems. This is one case, where using a template doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the second comment.