# moderncv: Vertical space between cvitems when section title spans more than one line

Tags: spacing, moderncv, vertical

Using the `fancy` style, if my section title is longer than one line, `cvitem`s (as well as `cvdoubleitem`s) have additional vertical space after the first item. This seems to depend on the "height" of the section title.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{fancy}
\moderncvcolor{grey}

\firstname{Some}
\familyname{Guy}
\phone[mobile]{123456789} 
\phone[fixed]{123456789}
\email{some@mail.com}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{section title spanning more than one line}
\cvitem{some entry, doesn't really matter}{doesn't matter either}
\cvitem{some second entry, doesn't really matter}{doesn't matter either}
\cvitem{third entry, doesn't really matter}{doesn't matter either}

\section{section title spanning more than one line, again}
\cvdoubleitem{some entry,}{doesn't really matter}{doesn't matter}{ either}
\cvdoubleitem{some second entry,}{ doesn't really matter}{doesn't}{ matter either}
\cvdoubleitem{third entry, doesn't}{ really matter}{doesn't matter}{ either}

\end{document}
```

I want the same vertical space between the first and the second item as I get between the second and the third. Using `\vspace` to create "negative vertical space" didn't work, and neither did putting negative units as the optional argument in `\cvitem` (e.g. `\cvitem[-15pt]{...}` ).

Is there a way to achieve what I want? Thanks for your help!

Edit: A similar question has been asked before, but the answers aren't promising: [Spacing in moderncv fancy theme with multiple line captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372001/spacing-in-moderncv-fancy-theme-with-multiple-line-captions?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the `fancy` style of `moderncv` is designed to have only a **short**, a very short section, not a longer one.

Therefore the short answer is simple: 
no, with style `fancy` it is **not possible** what you want.

A little bit longer:
To realize what you want the style has to be completly 
rewritten to include sections and cvitems in a table.  That is a lot of work and results at last in writting a **complete new style**.

Better use the other styles `classic` or `casual` if you need longer sections.